# xPath doesn't go on to the next page

Tags: python, testing, firefox, selenium-webdriver, xpath

When I use below code, the website doesn't go on to the next page.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class ProductPurchase(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Purchase the product on the website http://automationpractice.com/index.php
    """
    # Preconditions
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php")
        self.driver.maximize_window()
    def teardown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
    # Buying a product on the website 
    def test_wrong_agreement(self):
        driver = self.webdriver
        time.sleep(2)
    #Click on "Quick view"
        quickview_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/div/div[1]/div/a[2]").click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

It should go on to the next page but xPath doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and good luck on learning test automation.

The first thing I do when an xpath does not work is to check it, usually using an extension like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-finder/ihnknokegkbpmofmafnkoadfjkhlogph) one to make sure it is correct. Additionally, it is better to use a shorter xpath so there is less room for mistake i.e. `"//img[@title='Printed Dress']"`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following xpath and use javaScript executor to click on `Quick View`
This code will click 1st element on the page.If you wish to click all `Quick Viw` button sequentially you need to write logic further.

```
driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php")
driver.maximize_window()
ele_Quikview=driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//a[@class="quick-view"])[1]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",ele_Quikview)
```